# Pandas scatterplot returns error when trying to pass a list for color

Tags: python, pandas, colors, dataframe, scatter

I'm working with the sklearn boston dataset. Here is how I've manipulated the data:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from random import shuffle
boston = load_boston()
seed(0)  # Creates a replicable shuffling
new_index = range(boston.data.shape[0])
shuffle(new_index) # shuffling the index
X, y = boston.data[new_index], boston.target[new_index]
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=boston.feature_names)

colors = ['k' if v > np.mean(y) else 'w' for v in y]

scatter = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='RM', y='LSTAT', c=colors)
```

I'm getting an error that states "unhashable type: 'list'". I'm not sure what's wrong, especially since I got this code from a python book I'm working with (Python for Data Science for Dummies). Any idea why this scatter plot won't work?

Comment: Works for me using Pandas 0.16.2.  Which version are you using?

Comment: 0.15.0, I'll update!

Comment: I also changed `seed(0)` to `np.random.seed(0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I was using an old version of pandas. After updating to pandas 0.17.0, the problem was resolved.